# Click event handler is called n-1 times the click number

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the page there is a list of dates. To the right of each date are two icons: update and delete. I want to catch the data-update_url, and data-delete_url.

The problem is that when I click on, say, update icon, nothing happens.
Another click makes it show alert message. Another click makes shows alert message twice. And so on. That is alert message is shown n-1 clicks number.

I tried to model it at jsfiddle. But failed.

Well, could you suggest what may be the reason of such behaviour?

```
<li>03 January 2016
<a class="update" id="update_framedate_26" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-update_url="/frame_date/26/update/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
<a class="delete" id="remove_framedate_26" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-delete_url="/frame_date/26/delete/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>


<li>15 January 2015 
<a class="update" id="update_framedate_27" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-update_url="/frame_date/27/update/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
<a class="delete" id="remove_framedate_27" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-delete_url="/frame_date/27/delete/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>



<script>
function get_form(url){
    var update_url = url.target.getAttribute('data-update_url');
    var delete_url = url.target.getAttribute('data-delete_url');

    var cuaghtUrl = update_url || delete_url;

    alert(cuaghtUrl);
}

function handle_update_buttons(){
    var update_button_list = $(".update");
    $(update_button_list).click(function() {
        $(this).click(get_form);
    })
}

function handle_update_buttons(){
    var update_button_list = $(".update");
    $(update_button_list).click(function() {
        $(this).click(get_form);
    })
}

 function handle_delete_buttons(){
    var delete_button_list = $(".delete");
     $(delete_button_list).click(function() {
         $(this).click(get_form);
    });
}

handle_update_buttons();
handle_delete_buttons();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have two identical `handle_update_buttons` functions?

Comment: And how do you call `handle_update_buttons()`? I guess you are calling it on click which then bound a new click handler on each click. Your code doesn't really make sense regarding provided context

Comment: You have a mistaken pattern in your code. It's not the problem, but it suggests that you need to spend more time going through jQuery tutorials. You have `var update_button_list = $(".update");` followed by `$(update_button_list).click(...)`. `update_button_list` *already* refers to a jQuery object, there's no need to run it through `$()` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code hooks up a click handler that, *every time* it's called, will hook up a click handler calling `get_form`:

```
function handle_update_buttons(){
    var update_button_list = $(".update");
    // ------------------vvvvvv
    $(update_button_list).click(function() {
        $(this).click(get_form);
    // --------^^^^^^
    })
}
```

Note the arrows in the comments. So the first time, it just hooks up the second handler and that's all. The second time, it hooks up a handler **again** and then the handler from the first call is fired. The thrid time, it hooks up a handler for the third time, and the first two handlers are triggered. And so on.

You probably meant to do this:

```
function handle_update_buttons(){
    $(".update").click(get_form);
}
```

...which just hooks up a handler **once**, which will call `get_form` on each click.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding another handler on every click event.

Let's look at your code:

```
$(update_button_list).click(function() {
    $(this).click(get_form);
})
```

What it does is:

- It attaches a "click" event handler, which, **when invoked** (when a user click on your element):

  - Will attach `get_form` callback on `$(this)` element

I assume you wanted to simply invoke your `get_form` callback on first click, so instead of reattaching it (again and again on every other click), just call it:

```
$(update_button_list).click(function() {
    var url = ... set this variable to whatever you want it to be ...
    get_form(url);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is you are attaching click event all the time.
It dosnt required to be attached all the time.
Please look at below code here

```
 $(update_button_list).click(function() {
get_form($(this));
```

})
attached only one time it works all the time.
Hope this helps.

```js
function get_form(url) {
  var update_url = url.parent().find('span[data-update_url]').attr('data-update_url');
  var delete_url = url.parent().find('span[data-update_url]').attr('data-delete_url');
  var cuaghtUrl = update_url || delete_url;
  alert(cuaghtUrl);
}

function handle_update_buttons() {
  var update_button_list = $(".update");
  $(update_button_list).click(function() {
    get_form($(this));
  })
}

function handle_update_buttons() {
  var update_button_list = $(".update");
  $(update_button_list).click(function() {
    get_form($(this));
  })
}

function handle_delete_buttons() {
  var delete_button_list = $(".delete");
  $(delete_button_list).click(function() {
    get_form($(this));
  });
}

handle_update_buttons();
handle_delete_buttons();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<li>03 January 2016
  <a class="update" id="update_framedate_26" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-update_url="/frame_date/26/update/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  <a class="delete" id="remove_framedate_26" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-delete_url="/frame_date/26/delete/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>


<li>15 January 2015
  <a class="update" id="update_framedate_27" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-update_url="/frame_date/27/update/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
  <a class="delete" id="remove_framedate_27" href="javascript:void(0)"><span data-delete_url="/frame_date/27/delete/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</li>
```